# Prove that $\lVert x-y \rVert < 5$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I got stuck with one proof from analysis and would appreciate some hints:

If  $\lVert x-z \rVert < 2$ and  $\lVert y-z \rVert < 3$, prove that $\lVert x-y \rVert < 5$.

Here's my attempt:

$5 > \lVert x-z \rVert + \lVert y-z \rVert \geq \lVert x-z+y-z \rVert = \lVert x+y-2z \rVert \geq \lVert x-y-2z \rVert \geq \lVert x-y \rVert - \lVert 2z \rVert$. And that's where I'm stuck...

Comment: $x - y = x - z + z - y$

Comment: and triangle inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint. Use the triangle inequality, this is a direct result of it.

Also, note that the norm is symmetric, i.e. $\lVert z-y \rVert =\lVert y-z \rVert$